# Let $X$ be the number of trials until you roll two ones. Derive a formula for $P(X > x)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X \sim \textrm{Geom}(p)$ on $\{1, 2,\dotsc\}$. Roll a pair of dice until you get two ones on the same roll. Let $X$ be the number of trials when you stop. Derive a formula for $P(X > x)$

I found the formula to $P(X = x)$ which is $\left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^{x-1}\frac {1}{36}$.

I'm just confused with what $P(X > x)$ means.

Comment: $P(X > x) = P(X = x + 1) + P(X = x + 2) + P(X = x+ 3) + \cdots$.

Comment: Or, what might be easier to calculate, $P(X>x)=1-P(X\leq x)=1-\sum_{k\leq x}P(X=k)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a summation, as noted in the comments. Or we can notice that $P(X> x) = P(X\geq x+1)$. In words, this means we have fail the first $x$ trails; success has to happen on the $x+1$ trial, or the $x+2$ trial, etc. The probability of failing on any particular trial is 
$$1-P(\text{double ones}) = 1-\frac 16\frac 16  =\frac{35}{36}.$$
Hence
$$P(X\geq x+1) = P(\text{fail first $x$ trials}) = \left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^x.$$

Comment: Why don't you consider the (1/36) success trial for P(X>x)?

Comment: Because I'm not interested in doing it that way. If you want to consider the success, then you have to do a summation. In other words, you literally do $P(X>x) = P(X = x+1\cup X = x+2\cup \dotsb) = P\left(\bigcup_{k = x+1}^\infty X = k\right)$ and then do summation. Instead, I used reasoning and did it a nicer way.